# How to Run bcp command over a SQL Server Directly

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage-account

How can I run the SQL Server Directly onto the sql server vm, I have a azure file share mounted on the virtual machine but when I try to run the below command:

```
use SVDB
Declare @CMDString VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CMDString = 'bcp test.dbo1.ORG out Z:\ORG.txt -T -c'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CMDString;
```

It gives me below error:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL
```

Let me remind you all that I am doing this into the Azure file share, but this is not working there??
There is nothing linked to permission or something in the azure file share

Comment: Don't use Drive Letters, use UNC paths; unless the Drive itself is located on that actual server (which i would hazard a guess it is not as it's `Z:\ `). Give that a try first.

Comment: Is your Z drive shared ? Try making a folder inside Z and grant access to the folder for everyone.
Or use UNC: 
**out //111.11.11.111/sharedFolder/ORG.txt**

Comment: You mean to say grant permission over the shared folder in azure file share??

Comment: How can I use IP address here as its a file share?

Comment: if it's a Share, don't use a Drive letter, as I said. Use the UNC path. I don't know what "Z:\" represents, but UNC paths look like this: `\\[Servername]\[ShareName]\[Directory]\[Filename].txt`. Replace the sections in the square brackets with the appropriate values for your share.

Answer (score 0):

Check these 3 things:

1) The path/filename is incorrect (check your typing / spelling)

2) The file does not exist. (make sure the file is where you expect it to be)

3) The file is already open by some other app. (close the other app to release the file)

Comment: File is not linked with any other service, nor the path or file name is incorrect

Comment: What about the file permissions ?

Comment: I am writing directly from the server why is there a need of file permission.

Comment: Check out this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9c26d2a1-4d40-4646-a82d-7858664ab3b6/can-bcp-a-file-to-a-unc-from-a-command-prompt-but-not-from-sql?forum=sqltools

Comment: I have a Azure file share mapped as a network drive, then Why is there need of a file permission here? And I am directly writing into it then why there is a requirement of file share?